# How to automatically store images from parent entity to child in sonata admin

Tags: php, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I got stuck and I can't figure out how to solve this problem. I am using **symfony 3.4** and **sonata admin**. I have tow entities classes called **Certificate** and **CertificateImage** with the following relationships:

```
    class Certificate 
{
        /**
     * @var Certificate
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CMS3\CoreBundle\Entity\Certificate", inversedBy="child")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
     * })
     */
    private $parent;


        /**
     * @var Certificate
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CMS3\CoreBundle\Entity\Certificate", mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $child;

        /**
     * @var CertificateImage[]|Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CMS3\CoreBundle\Entity\CertificateImage", mappedBy="certificate", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $images;

    // getters and setters 
}

class CertificateImage 
{
     /**
     * @var Media
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $image;

        /**
     * @var Certificate
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CMS3\CoreBundle\Entity\Certificate", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="certificate_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $certificate;

    // getters and setters
}
```

My goal: How can I automatically store images from **parent Certificate** **to child Certificate** when creating parent certificate images from sonata configureFormFields method?
    I really appreciate any idea about how I can achieve this. Thanks in advance.
    [image: enter code here]

Comment: You can do that in the `addImage()` method of the parent entity where you just set the parent image to the children.

Comment: Ugo T, thanks for your reply. I've set the image for the child certificate within this method, and he did't work. I don't know why. Within the addImage the child certificate object is null. This is how I did it, please check: https://pastebin.com/zE13dAXP

Comment: I have added a new image. This button is for adding a new certificate for child. Please, any tips about how I can fill it with image from parent certificate?

Answer (score 0):

To add an image to your child entity, you have to duplicate the TicketImage instance, because its foreign key will be the parent one. You can try to do it like this (not sure, it's difficult to figure it out without the full code) :

```
public function addImage(TicketImage $image): Ticket
 {
    $this->images->add($image);
    $image->setTicket($this); // works
    foreach($this->child as $child) {
        $cloneImg = clone $image;
        $cloneImg->setId(null);
        $cloneImg->setTicket($child);
        $child->setImage($cloneImg);
    }

    return $this;
 }
```

But I think this way looks like a hack so a better solution could be to think again your code and maybe try to reach the parent image from the children using a getter in the children like that :

```
public function getImage(): TicketImage 
 {
    return $this->parent->getImages();
 }
```